# Change data with preg_replace_callback function

Tags: php, regex

I have a file with some data in the format of:

```
0101    Group1  01/13/13
0102    Group1  02/03/13
0103    Group1  03/05/13
0104    Group1  04/05/13
0201    Group2  04/19/13
0202    Group2  05/10/13
0301    Group3  07/13/13
0302    Group3  07/13/13
0303    Group3  07/13/13
0401    Group4  02/12/13
0501    Group5  05/29/13
```

I only have a total of `5` Groups. I am trying to replace each Group with a single letter value here.

```
Group1 will be replaced with A
Group2 will be replaced with B
Group3 will be replaced with C
Group4 will be replaced with D
Group5 will be replaced with E
```

I found a way to do this with preg_replace_callback.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/Group[1-5]/', 'id_callback', $text);

function id_callback($matches) {
  if ($matches[0] == 'Group1') {
    return 'A';
  } elseif ($matches[0] == 'Group2') {
    return 'B';
  } elseif ($matches[0] == 'Group3') {
    return 'C';
  } elseif ($matches[0] == 'Group4') {
    return 'D';
  } elseif ($matches[0] == 'Group5') {
    return 'E';
  }
}

echo $text;
```

Is there a way I can do this and get rid of all these if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematical relationships are a great help.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("/Group([1-5])/",function($m) {
    return chr(ord("A")+$m[1]-1);
},$text);
```

Comment: neat, i was writing an answer using an array, but this is cuter

Comment: There shouldn't be a place for "Cute" in programming IMO, clarity is where the beauty is at. :)

Answer (score 2):

A different approach for this would incline using an [`associative array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with either an [`anonymous/named`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) function 
leading to running the callback for every match that it finds and populating the match with the value from the array.

```
$map = array('Group1' => 'A', 'Group2' => 'B', 
             'Group3' => 'C', 'Group4' => 'D', 'Group5' => 'E');

$text = preg_replace_callback('/(?P<id>Group[1-5])/', 
      function($m) {
          global $map; 
          extract($m);
          return isset($map[$id]) ? $map[$id] : $m[0];
      }, $text);
```

**Note:** I replaced your regular expression with a [Named capturing Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) for readabilty.

> **Update**

As mentioned by [@Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol), here's a simple way to perform this using [strtr](http://php.net/strtr) to replace.

```
$text = _replace($text);

function _replace($t) {
  $map = array('Group1' => 'A', 'Group2' => 'B', 
               'Group3' => 'C', 'Group4' => 'D', 'Group5' => 'E'
  );
  return strtr($t, $map);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `global`, you can use `function($m) use ($map)` syntax for anonymous functions.

Comment: If you're starting with the associative array, why not use the cheaper [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) to perform the swap?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
$find = array('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4', 'Group5');
$replace = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$result = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```